# how to replace onerror src image with new image

Tags: javascript

For some reason , my photo.onerror image is not loading as i tab through the images and come upon one that doesn't have one set , the onerror image still wont load , see anything wrong with this ?

```
  if (document.getElementById("draft_player_photo")) {
     var photo = document.getElementById("draft_player_photo");
     photo.src = "http://www.myfantasyleague.com/player_photos_2013/" + pid + "_thumb.jpg";
     photo.alt = playerDatabase['pid_' + pid].name;
     photo.title = playerDatabase['pid_' + pid].name;
     photo.onerror = "this.onerror=null;this.src='http://www.myfantasyleague.com/player_photos_2010/no_photo_available.jpg';";
  }
```

Comment: That isn't jQuery by-the-way.

Comment: Can't you just iterate through all images with that id and set the src for each one to the one you want?

Comment: are you trying something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kn816rr1/

Comment: @MShack - the code you posted works. What is your question?

Comment: @MShack try this http://jsfiddle.net/kn816rr1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `photo.onerror` as a function, as you do it now you just assign a string to `onerror` :

```
..
photo.onerror = function() {
    this.src=this.getAttribute('fallback') //reuse of my original idea, but whatever works
}   
...
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zpLm0e7d/**

---

I would implement a fallback `src` :

```html
<img id="draft_player_photo" fallback="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif"src="http://www.myfantasyleague.com/player_photos_2013/11657_thumb.jpg" alt="this image">
```

and then catch any `onerror` and set the `src` to that fallback value :

```js
$('img').on('error', function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('fallback'))
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4p8gdppL/**

Sry for the w3fools reference, they have images with short length.